# Understanding Image Function In Context With Matrix

Tags: r

I have the following matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

which is a 3 by 3 matrix.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1
```

Passing the above matrix to the image function as :

```
image(mat)
```

produces something which looks like:

[image]

I cannot relate this picture to what I passed to the image function. What just happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's essentially rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise. This is explained in the help file at `?image` (emphasis mine):

> Notice that `image` interprets the `z` matrix as a table of `f(x[i], y[j])` values, so that the **x axis corresponds to row number and the y axis to column number, with column 1 at the bottom**, i.e. a 90 degree counter-clockwise rotation of the conventional printed layout of a matrix.

You can also see `fortunes::fortune("image")` for a bit of explanation:

> "Mathematical conventions are just that, conventions. They differ by field of mathematics. Don't ask us why matrix rows are numbered down but graphs are numbered up the y axis, nor why x comes before y but row before column. But the matrix layout has always seemed illogical to me."
>
> Brian D. Ripley, answering a question why the layouts of `print(x)` and `image(x)` are different
>
> R-help, August 2004